# Best way to architect unique identifier generation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an API in rails that will handle a lot of requests. Lets say millions a day. I want to be able to assign a unique id to each of these requests. The way i am doing it is starting with a uid of 3 letters/numbers and continue up till 9 letters/numbers when the previous bracket is all taken.

One one i am doing it is generate the uid in real time when the request comes, so the app will try to find the first available uid and assign it. But after a while i have the impression that this will impact the performance of the app.

The second way I am thinking is to auto-generate all the possible uids in advance and have a flag assigned to them [free/taken] so that when a request comes in i assign the first free uid to it, which should be very fast if that filed is indexed.

Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-uuid

Comment: The actual generation of the uid needs to be custom because of platform limitations. I have that piece working fine. So needs to be from 3 to 9 characters of the subset i have. I am just not sure on what architecture to use for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just generate a random string and assign it while it doesn't exist. Before I get into that let me just mention that `SecureRandom.uuid` is the best way to go. It generates random uuids whose chance of collision are mathematically improbable.

Anyway, here is a way to use your own custom random string generator that will only assign if it doesn't already exist:

```
def generate_random_uid
  begin
    uid = my_custom_random_string_method
    object.uid = uid
  end while ObjectModel.exists? uid: uid

  object.save
end
```

The do while block will execute once and set a variable called `uid` to be a random string you generate in the method `my_custom_random_string_method`, then in the while part it checks if a record exists whose `uid` attribute matches the random uid you just generated, if it does it runs the do block again, rinse and repeat until the expression in the while part returns false meaning the uid doesn't exists, then your object is saved and the uid written to the db. This guarantees that you will only ever save the `object` with a uid that doesn't exist in your db.

Comment: I will try to do a load test with this method. Will let you know as soon as i get done. Thanks diego.

Comment: Your solution will work. The only thing the syntax is wrong you need to have a loop do ... break unless cond end in ruby

Comment: Will this approach still work if i deploy the application to multiple servers and i receive 2 requests at the same time on 2 different servers?